# PHP require_once on spl_autoload, does not load in sub-folders

Tags: php

I am building a web-app from ground up and it is my first attempt at something like this.

I have an issue when doing `require_once`, from with in sub-directory.

Folder structure:

```
Root + browse  -> file.php
     + classes -> User.php
     + core    -> init.php
     +
     +
     -> index.php
     -> random.php
```

My every file start like this, and it works fine

```
<?php
require_once '/core/init.php';

# Head
require_once '/head.php';

$user = new User();

# Header
require_once '/header.php';
```

`head.php` and `header.php` are in the `root folder`, and pages work fine, like index.php and so on.

I get issue in my `browse->file.php`, and code looks like this :

```
<?php
require_once '../core/init.php';

# Head
require_once '../head.php';

$user = new User();

# Header
require_once '../header.php';
```

**Error:**

```
Warning: require_once(classes/User.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vagrant/vm/data/core/init.php on line 27

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'classes/User.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:') in /home/vagrant/vm/data/core/init.php on line 27
```

My `init.php` file:

```
session_start();

$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once 'classes/'.$class.'.php';
});

require_once $directory.'/classes/Hash.php';

require_once $directory.'/functions/sanitize.php';
```

I have even went ahead and added `$directory. '/classes/'.$class.'.php';`
That break the whole site..

I also tried referencing in my `file.php` with, $directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; and doing `require_once $directory.'/head.php'`

Did not work I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks guys!

Comment: The issue is likely to be that the `current working directory` - see `getcwd();` is not the same as the PHP file - see `__DIR__`. The relative path is based on `current working directory` not `__DIR__`. As mentioned in the answer - best to always use absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

> I am building a web-app from ground up and it is my first attempt at something like this.

Since you're building the new website, you should follow the specific of [PSR-0/4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). There are already autoloader PSR-0/4 compatible, but you can leave this job to [composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Going back to your problem, use absolute path when you can.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../classes/'.$class.'.php';
});
```

`__DIR__` is a magic constant, in this case represents the absolute path of the directory of `init.php`